# Cypresss Unable to Load UTF-16 Website on Brower Launch

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, cypress, utf-16

I have my Website Created with Meta Tag charset as UTF-16 in the Head Block
`<meta charset="utf-16">`
So if I Check my Site on Chrome Manually the Data is Loading Fine, But when try to Open the Site Through cy.visit() and Launch the Browser we are getting Gibberish Values

[Cypress Browse Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkRX5.png)

When I Inspect the Cypress I could see that the Cypress is using Charset UTF-8

[Cypress Inspect Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64U5Z.png)

There are no Extra PlugIns Installed just Cypress, The Version Cypress used is 13.7.0. I have updated it to this Version from 10.10.0

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the Cypress test runner (the main browser window), not the application under test.

The app is loaded into an `<iframe>` and that document has `<meta charset="utf-16">`. To find it, right-click/inspect some text element on your page, which takes you to the elements tab of dev-tools.

From there, look up the HTML tree to find the nearest `<head>` (not the one you show in the picture).

If your web page really has `utf-16` you will see the same in that head section.

To test, use this code which should pass (it does on my sample)

```js
cy.visit(my-url)
cy.get('head meta[charset]')
  .should('have.attr', 'charset', 'utf-16')
```